# Android fingerprint auth through alertdialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, fingerprint

I want to have the user use fingerprint authentication to allow them to perform an action within my app. I have already performed the necessary check, does the hardware exist, is a fingerprint registered etc when they say they would like to use fingerprint auth.

An alertdialog currently opens when it is time for the user to authenticate with their fingerprint. I'd like to know if it is actually possible to catch the fingerprint through an alertdialog as and alertdialog afaik only has positive and negative button input options.

If it is not possible to do this through an alertdialog, a point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Just to be clear, I don't mean using the screen as a fingerprint sensor.

Comment: hey, did you find a API 19+ solution for this?

Comment: Hi @swalkner. The accepted answer worked for me. If you need any help with it, I'll show you how mine's setup. :)

Comment: Hi @NobodyTellsMe, can you show how you did it? I can't get it working with the accepted answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this [**FingerprintDialog**](https://github.com/omaflak/FingerprintDialog-Library) library. Then it goes simply like this :

```
FingerprintDialog.initialize(this)
    .title(R.string.title)
    .message(R.string.message)
    .callback(new FingerprintCallback({
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess() {
            // Fingerprint recognized
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationCancel() {
            // User pressed cancel button
        }
    }))
    .show();
```

---

Otherwise, you just have to create a custom xml layout, get the view using a `LayoutInflater` and call `setView(view)` on the dialog. [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20custom%20alertdialog&oq=android%20custom%20alert%20dialog).

Comment: Ooh, that looks like a possibility. I'll come back once I've given it a go.

Comment: Oh, I, perhaps naively, assumed that I could simply place the above code where I wanted the authentication to take place. However, FingerprintDialog  requires the class to be manually created as far as I can tell. Is there no pre-built version of this?

Comment: You can, you just have to add this line `implementation 'me.aflak.libraries:fingerprintdialog:2.4.2'` to the `dependencies` section of the **app build.gradle**

Comment: Great library but only supports API 23+, any way to bypass this i need to support API 19+

Comment: Thanks @RonEskinder ! I guess I could, it's because of the `fill_color` attribute in the vector drawable files. The thing is I won't be home 'till the 10th of February so I can't really fix this now. For now, your best option would be to clone the repo and make some changes to it (shouldn't be that hard) or use another library.

Answer (score 0):

This currently isn't possible. Or if it is, I really doubt it. Most touch screen phones use a capacitive touch. Which means, since our fingers conduct electricity, we disturb the electric fields infront of the phone's screen. While it does support multitouch, I really doubt it's so precise that it detects the ridges on our fingers.

You would need more of a heat sensitive touch screen. Which I don't think they use in most new generation touch screens.

So you could use this API https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html but only in device that contains fingerprint scan and definitely not through the screen of you device.

Comment: Sorry, you've misunderstood. I am aware the screen can't detect fingerprints :). I mean I want to prompt the user for a fingerprint and handle it through an alertdialog.

Comment: @BoshJailey ouch sorry. Then you can handle it. You can customize your alertDialog as you need. Can you specify your question, what is your problem or what do you want to achieve.  If you want just notify user that he have to use fingerprint scanner right now just put the message in setMessage method:)

Comment: Yeah, I've got the AlertDialog to appear but an alert dialog only afaik has "setPositiveButton" and "setNegativeButton". I want the user to have the dialog appear and be able to then put their finger on the sensor and have the application authenticate with the alertdialog. Almost as if the act of giving the fingerprint is the 'positive button'.